# How to initialize object attributes from an array of strings in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses, setattr, object-initialization, arrayofstring

I am supposed to write a class which will allow the user of the script to **define what attributes will it's objects have when initializing** them by giving it an array of strings like this.

```py
data = Database(tables=['distance', 'speed'])
```

Then it should be possible to call the class's methods like

```py
data.distance.insert({1: 25, 2: 55})
data.speed.mean()
```

etc.

**I have tried using `setattr()`** this way

```py
data = Database()
tables=['distance', 'speed']
for item in tables:
    setattr(data, item, item)
```

which works, but isn't exactly what it should be.

Any ideas how to do it directly **inside the class?**